# Why is the following sentence inverted?

Tags: grammar

"With love comes responsibility."

How is it different from "Responsibility comes with love"? And would it be incorrect to say  "Love with responsibility comes"?

Answer (score 1):

It is about style, it is about emphasizing something.

> With love comes responsibility

is a perfect way to tell someone that if you *love* someone, you should be equally capable enough to fulfill the responsibility.

On the other hand, *responsibility comes with love* becomes a general statement and probably would change the *order*. The former one has love *coming first* and the latter one has *responsibility occuring prior to love!*

Lastly, *Love with responsibility comes* is weird.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simply a stylistic choice. They are ordered that way because it means that one leads to another - ie, when you love somebody, that brings with it responsibility, perhaps towards the other person.

In this case, you can't invert the sentence because it wouldn't have the same meaning, or make sense. There are many different kinds of responsibility, and not all are connected to love. Saying "with responsibility brings love" would imply that whenever you receive any kind of responsibility, you receive love as a result - and that just isn't true. I'm not just stating that as a matter of opinion, either. For example, many people would agree that "children bring joy". There might be a few that don't agree. But you couldn't say "joy brings children", as there are many kinds of joy that *don't* lead to having children.

Even things that come as a package would not necessarily work if the order was inverted. A restaurant might say "the steaks come with fries", but it wouldn't necessarily be true that "the fries come with steaks" if they sold fries separately. You could only really invert a statement like yours if the two things were intrinsically *and exclusively* linked.